# Issues with Java HashMap and key Object I rolled myself

Tags: java, hashmap

So, I'm trying to use a `HashMap` to map my own `Object` to a `String` value. My object is below (with some code removed for brevity)

```
public class RouteHeadsignPair {
    String route;
    String headsign;

    public RouteHeadsignPair(String n_route, String n_headsign) {
        route = n_route.toLowerCase();
        headsign = n_headsign.toLowerCase();
    }

    public String getRoute () {
        return route;
    }

    public String getHeadsign() {
        return headsign;
    }

    public boolean equals(RouteHeadsignPair other) {
        return(other.getRoute().equals(route) && other.getHeadsign().equals(headsign));
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return(route.hashCode());
    }
}
```

I'm mapping a bunch of these objects to Strings by loading data from a text file. Later on, based on (independent) user input, I try to query the `HashMap` using a `RouteHeadsignPair` Object. containsKey() returns false and get() returns null, as if I had never added the key into the map. But, bizarrely, if I iterate over the map using the below code (where `newKey` is a `RouteHeadsignPair` made from user input)

```
RouteHeadsignPair foundKey = null;
Iterator<RouteHeadsignPair> keysInMap = routeHeadsignToStopIdMap.keySet().iterator();
while(keysInMap.hasNext()) {
    RouteHeadsignPair currKey = keysInMap.next();

    if(currKey.equals(newKey)) {
        System.err.println("Did find a key with an equals() == true!");
        foundKey = currKey;
    }
}

System.err.println("Value in map? " + routeHeadsignToStopIdMap.containsKey(newKey)  + "( hashcode = " + newKey.hashCode() + 
        ", equals = " + newKey.equals(foundKey) + ")");
System.err.println("foundKey in map? " + routeHeadsignToStopIdMap.containsKey(foundKey)  + "( hashcode = " + foundKey.hashCode() + 
        ", equals = " + foundKey.equals(newKey) + ")" );
```

*I apologize for the code formatting, it's late and I'm getting cranky*

I get the following output

```
Did find a key with an equals() == true!
```

and then

```
Value in map? false( hashcode = 1695, equals = true)
foundKey in map? true( hashcode = 1695, equals = true)
```

So, if I iterate over the keys and look for keys that return `equals()`, I do find one, and the `hashCode()` is the same for both of these. If the `hashCode()` is the same for `newKey` and `foundKey` and `foundKey.equals(newKey)` returns true, shouldn't `HashMap.get(key)` return a value and `containsKey()` return true? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not overriding `Object.equals` - you're *overloading* it because of the parameter type. Your *diagnostic* code calls your overload, but the map code doesn't (as it doesn't know about it).

You need a method with a signature of

```
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

If you use the `@Override` annotation you'll get an error if you fail to override something properly.

You'll need to check whether `other` is an instance of `RouteHeadSignPair` first, then cast. If you make the `RouteHeadSignPair` class final, you won't need to worry about whether or not it's the exact same class, etc.

Note that your hash codes will collide unnecessarily, by the way - if you use both the `route` *and* the `headSign` hashes to generate your hash code, it may help your map lookups to be more efficient. (If there are several instances with the same route but different head signs, it's useful if the map doesn't have to check for equality on all of them when looking up a key.)

Comment: I would also suggest him to add null checking or inverse equals() calls

Comment: @EugenMartynov: I'm not sure what you mean by "inverse equals calls" but yes, there's more to do. Will edit.

Comment: yeah, I was using (route.hashCode() ^ headsign.hashCode()) as my hashCode() result, but simplified it while debugging. I'll at most have two headsigns per route anyway so it's not a big deal.

Comment: @JonSkeet `instanceof` will handle null case. Great answer